# Proving well ordering is total relation

Tags: relations, order-theory

Assuming R is well-ordered relation on a set A. Wikipedia claims that every well ordered relation is also a total one.Even tough in first sight it seems trivial, how can I prove it?

Comment: There’s nothing to prove: it’s part of the definition of well-ordering.

Comment: What is a well-ordered relation? Do you mean a well-ordering or a well-founded relation?

Comment: I meant well ordering.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis A well-ordering is a total ordering by definition.

Comment: A well-order may be defined without the restriction that it must be linear as it can be proved as soon as any set has a minimum. Both variations with and without the linearity restrictions are used by mathematicians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of contradiction, take an antichain $C \subseteq A$ in the well-ordered set $(A, \leq)$, that is a set of pairwise non-comparable elements ($\forall x,y \in C, x \not \leq y \text{ and }  y \not \leq x$). Thus it contains many minimal but no smallest element. On the other hand $C$ contains a smallest element as $\leq$ is a well-order. This is a contradiction.

> **Definition** (minimal, smallest element)
>
> If $(A, \leq)$ is a partially ordered set, $X$ is a nonempty subset of $A$, and $a \in A$, then
>
> - $a$ is a *minimal* element of $X$ if $a \in X$ and $\forall x \in X, x \not \leq a$;
> - $a$ is the *smallest* element of $X$ if $a \in X$ and $\forall x \in X, a \leq x \lor a = x$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You might want to add the definitions for 'minimal' and 'smallest' elements, though - a least I would find it useful, because the terms are more or less equivalent in non-Mathematical English, unlike when interpreted Mathematically.

Comment: In short: There may be several minimal elements. A minimal element is a smallest element iff it is unique, i.e. iff there are no other minimal elements.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, you only need to take a pair $\{a,b\}$ of a well-ordered set such that $a \neq b$ , now this pair has a minimum element, so either $a < b$ or $b < a$.